# Can someone please clarify what this is asking me to do?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, random, allocation

[image]

I understand the creation of the array (int** intptrArray[5]) and the rand() number part. However, I don't understand the sentence in the middle - I know I need to allocate the array first and then allocate each pointer in the array to an int but I'm not sure how to go about it and I've been stuck for hours on this. Do I need to use malloc here and how would I do that?

Comment: Ask your **instructor.**  Your teacher cannot read your mind and will not know that you need a "nudge" unless you ask *him or her.*  Maybe the point needs to be clarified for a number of people in your class!  But, if you don't ask *him or her,* (s)he has no way to know.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then `int** intptrArray[5]` is *not* the answer! More likely, you'll want `int** intptrArray = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));` or something equivalent.

Comment: (Yes, I have *been* an instructor, and "this is one of my pet peeves.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to declare in the file scope a variable of the pointer type int ** like

```
int **intptrArray;
```

then in a function (for example in `main`) you need to allocate an array of `5` elements of the type `int *` like

```
intptrArray = malloc( 5 * sizeof( int * ) );
```

Then in a loop each element of the array should be initialized by a pointer to dynamically allocate memory for one object of the type `int`.

And then using the function `rand` you need to assign values to these integers.

For example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    intptrArray[i] = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    *intptrArray[i] = rand();
}
```

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Arrays do not have the type int **.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 In the assignment there is written "(i.e. int**)" Otherwise there would be written "(i.e. int *[5])"

Answer (score 1):

The requirement

> create an array of int * (i.e., int **)

is a contradiction. A object can be a array or a pointer, a array of pointers, a pointer to a array or some combination of it. But a pointer is not the same as a array and a array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array. Arrays do often decay to pointers when you access them but there are still 2 different concepts.

An array can have the type `int *intptrArray[]`, the type `int **intptrPtr` is a pointer to pointer to `int`, this includes the possibility of a pointer to an array of pointers to `int`, a pointer to a pointer to an array of `int` or a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of `int`.

The requirement

> of size 5

is misleading. According to the C standard, the size of an object is measured in bytes. Creating an array of size 5 with `int *` is often not possible because a pointer has the size of 4 or 8 bytes on many platforms. C standard does not limit the possible size of a pointer, so 5 is a possibility but i never saw a machine that supports this. I think he meant the length of the array.

I think it is best to ask the guy that gave you this requirement for clarification.